# Using Nant's msbuild task, is there a way to get msbuild's colors to work?

Tags: msbuild, nant

Title pretty much says it all.  When I run msbuild by itself, it displays a lot of pretty colors in it's output, that helps a lot in highlighting where the problems are.  Our processes have a lot of external tasks, that haven't made the process easy to contain in msbuild by itself (Another topic, in any case).

So, is there way to keep the colored output of msbuild within a NANT msbuild task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. NAnt captures MSBuild output into a text buffer, MSBuild detects that it's not outputting to the console and disables the colouring.

Also, do you really need to use *both* MSBuild and NAnt? Those tools have practically 100% overlap, except that NAnt does not integrate with Visual Studio.

Comment: As far as just ditching Nant completely, I mentioned, it's pretty much another question, but we have a bunch of legacy Nant files, that call just call msbuild with the solution file (so, much like building from VS), along with an bunch of external commands, such as updating src ctrl, running tests, packing installers, etc.  So, thus far, just using the solution file with msbuild.  How much of a hurdler to completely migrate to msbuild?

Comment: For external commands - MSBuild has `<Exec>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx , simmilar to NAnt. It's mostly a problem if you're using complex functions/logic on NAnt side - translating this requires a person that knows both build system well.